$\langle{Tx, x}\rangle = 0$ implies $x$ is in $\ker(T)$
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T$ be a self-adjoint operator on $H$. I was wondering if the following result is true:
$$ \langle{Tx, x}\rangle = 0 \iff x \in \ker(T).$$
I am not even sure if the above is true but if it is, then my attempt of a proof is as follows.
$\textbf{Attempt.}$
We know that $(\ker(T))^\perp = \text{im}(T)$ since $T$ is self-adjoint. So $\ker(T) \perp \text{im}(T)$.
So since $Tx \in \text{im}(T)$, we have that $\langle{Tx, x}\rangle=0$ iff $Tx \perp x$ iff $x \in \ker(T)$.
Any verification that the above is true or false would be appreciated!

This is not true in general. Consider $T$ being the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\0&-1
\end{pmatrix}
and $x=(\sqrt 2;2)$. Then $x^{\mathsf{T}}Tx=0$ but $Tx=(2\sqrt 2;-2)$.

Hi LZX, thank you for the counter-example. Do you know where in my attempt the logic fails? Is it because in order for us to conclude that $x \in (\text{im}(T))^\perp = \ker(T)$, we require $x$ to be orthogonal to any $y \in \text{im}(T)$ and not just be orthogonal to $Tx$?

Hi @Aester, that's exactly where the logic fails; the last iff in your question does not hold.
